# How to perform cartesian product in PDL

Tags: perl, cartesian-product, pdl

I want to take an arbitrary 1D vector **a = [k]** and **b = [m]** and form the matrix of ordered pairs **c = [2 x k x m]** such that `$c->(:,(i),(j)) = [ $a->(i), $b->(j) ]`. I.e. the set of all ordered pairs of the elements in **a** and **b** a.k.a the cartesian product.

Of course I *could* use a loop and the [glue] function to accomplish this, but that isn't in the spirit of Perl/PDL. Is there a fancy method that involves slices, dummy dimensions, and glue that gets me there?

Also, using Math::Cartesian::Product (as answered here: [In Perl, how can I get the Cartesian product of multiple sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457096/in-perl-how-can-i-get-the-cartesian-product-of-multiple-sets) is cheating! :3 I want straight perl/PDL and hopefully learn something in the process.

Comment: So, what have you tried? post your code, show where it failed, else you will not get any help. This is not a code writing service website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got something that meets my criteria:

```
my $a = pdl 1,2,3,4;
my $b = pdl 5,6,7;
print "a = $a\n";
print "b = $b\n";
print "dummy dimensioned:\n";
$a = $a->dummy(0,$b->dim(0));
print "a".$a->shape." = $a\n";

$b = $b->dummy(0, $a->dim(1))->transpose;
print "b".$b->shape." = $b\n";

print "Glued together:\n"
my $c = $a->dummy(0,1)->glue(0, $b->dummy(0,1));
print "c".$c->shape." = $c\n";
```

---

```
a = [1 2 3 4]  
b = [5 6 7]  
dummy dimensioned:  
a[3 4] = 
[
 [1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]
 [4 4 4]
]

b[3 4] = 
[
 [5 6 7]
 [5 6 7]
 [5 6 7]
 [5 6 7]
]  
Glued together:  
c[2 3 4] = [[[1 5][1 6][1 7]][[2 5][2 6][2 7]][[3 5][3 6][3 7]][[4 5][4 6][4 7]]]
```